# Babel-register for backend nodejs: How to use relative import And improve performance

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using the following code for my backend nodejs to enable es6.

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'env' ]
})

// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./server.js')
```

In server.js, I use import style instead of require style to include other files and features. However, I need to specify full paths to those files. Examples are below.

```
import { ModuleA } from '../../../oh/my/god/still/more/../at/last/moduleA'
```

How can I set up relative imports? Also is it recommended to run the whole backend like this? I mean if there is any impact on performance since the code is not compiled to normal require code before running.